# How to return the status of processing methods(C#) in web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webservices-client

I have created 3 methods for "Reading data from DB", "Data Transfer" and "Insert to another DB" in .net web service.
My question is how to returning the status(custom message) of each methods to requested client?
eg: While Method one is running, client status has to display like "Reading Database processing". While second method is running, has to display like "Reading Database completed. Data transfer processing." Is it possible? or is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR).. Its quite easy to use and sounds like it might solve your problem.